# How to display an image in a CustomView based on a TableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm new to `Cocoa/Objective-c` so please bear with me on this.

I'm trying to create a simple program that has a `TableView` on the left of the window and a CustomView on the right. The TableView has 3 columns: `(NSString) name, (NSInteger) x, (NSInteger) y.` The x and y values are randomly generated between 0 and 100 whenever a new row is added. I have a simple Star class to hold these three attributes. The TableView seems to be working just fine.

On the right, I have a `CustomView` where I want to load an image whenever a new row is added to the `tableview` at the x,y for that entry.

I created this `"addStar"` method in the `CustomView` class, which is an `NSView`. Then, in my TableViewController class, I'm trying to call the `"addStar"` method in my "add" method that adds a new row.

When I launch the program, I'm able to add items to the `TableView`, but nothing shows up in the `CustomView`. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong here?

**CustomView.m**

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];

    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
}

- (void)addStar:(float)x and:(float)y
{
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(x, y, 35, 35);
    imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [imageView setImageScaling:NSScaleNone];
    [imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
}

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomView.h"
#import "Star.h"

@implementation TableViewController


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [list count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Star *s = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    return [s valueForKey:identifier];
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Star *s = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    [s setValue:object forKey:identifier];
}

// Add row to the tableview
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    Star *star = [[Star alloc] init];
    [list addObject:star];
    [tableView reloadData];

 // add star to the custom view
    CustomView* cv = [[CustomView alloc] init];
    [cv addStar:(float)[star xCoordinate] and:(float)[star yCoordinate]];

    [star release];
}

- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender {
    NSInteger row = [tableView selectedRow];
    [tableView abortEditing];
    if (row != -1)
        [list removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [list release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On right side you have Custom view And also you are creating new one as below...

```
CustomView* cv = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[cv addStar:(float)[star xCoordinate] and:(float)[star yCoordinate]];
```

But you are not adding this cv object on the screen.

write,

```
[self addSubview:cv];//add this below above code as you are creating new object each time.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question. That code is in the TableViewController.m file and there is no "view" to call addSubview. self.view gives an error. 

I thought that calling [self addSubview:imageView] within the addStar method would be enough.

Comment: But this will add the imageview on Customview. but CustomView which is allocated is not added yet on the screen Make sure when you add the sub view each time before that remove the previous sub views so that it will not add the multiples view on the same view.

Comment: I see what you mean, and it makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, I'm still having trouble calling addSubview from within the TableViewController. I'm getting an error in the console '[TableViewController addSubview:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000039ae0'. Is there another way I can access addSubview?

Comment: Is that TableViewController and CustomView have same pareviewcontroller?? can u pls tell me the hierarchy of views

Comment: That's all I have. One TableView and one CustomView. So should I put them both inside another View?

Comment: I think that will be better if you put it in another view controller like split view controller logic. Then from tableviewcontroller pass index of selected cell to parentviewcontroller and from then use can easily access subview for customview